# JVM memory settings impact

Tags: java, performance, memory, memory-management, jvm

I am trying to find out optimal memory settings for a web application that we have. This application requires retrieval of large data sets and results in high memory usage.

I wrote a small program to test JVM memory settings, this code basically floods memory with dummy objects.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Dummy{
    public final long v1 = 132132343243245L;
    public final long v2 = 132132343243245L;
    public final long v3 = 132132343243245L;
    public final long v4 = 132132343243245L;
}

public class MemoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FileWriter fw = null;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try{
            fw  = new FileWriter("out.txt");
            ArrayList<Dummy> alDummies = new ArrayList<Dummy>();
            for(int i =0 ; i < 1000; i++){
                long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for(int j=0; j< 10000; j++){
                    alDummies.add(new Dummy());
                }
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                fw.write(Long.toString(end-begin) + "\n");
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(fw != null)
                try {
                    long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    fw.write("Total: " + Long.toString(finish-start));
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }

}
```

This is what happened when I ran the code with various memory settings.

```
-Xms512M  -Xmx512M:  Errors out with insufficient memory.
-Xms768M  -Xmx768M:  Took total time of ~3300ms
-Xms1G  -Xmx1G:  Took total time of ~450ms
-Xms2G  -Xmx2G:  Took total time of ~500ms
```

all these are average of 10 runs.

I can understand the performance improvement from 768M to 1G , I guess JVM had to do less of memory page movements.

**However I do not understand the performance degradation from 1G to 2G, why is it performing slower with higher amount of memory?**

I do not know if it matters I am using mac pro with 16G memory and 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: try with more runs. The difference might tend to 0

Comment: The initial memory allocation may take more time - if you run the test for 30 seconds instead of 0.5 sec you will probably see different results.

Comment: You are creating just under a 1 GB of retained objects.  If you make the eden size larger you can avoid GCs.  try `-Xmn1500m` for the `-Xmx2g` test to increase the eden size.  BTW I would say a 32 GB heap is medium sized these days. ;)

Comment: Adding lots of objects to a default `ArrayList` causes lots of internal reallocations each time the internal array gets full. Instantiate with `ArrayList(1000000000)` to prevent this and allow less memory usage.

Comment: Unfortunately your test is a bit useless. First, your web app will run on server for long time, not just hit and run, so there will be lot other aspects impacting performance - for example jit. Second it may also depend on GC settings. So create your app, enable verbose gc, and base on that tune your app.

Comment: As @Gas touches, your test is useless and in this particular case it could very well be that you're using the default parallel GC and that the extra time is the extra time neded for a full stop when you have successfully used up all of the 2G.

Comment: @Gas I disagree that my test is useless, I have a working application which deteriorates when the -Xms4G -Xmx4G  compared to -Xms2G -Xmx2G.

Comment: It is useless. In Java everything below 1 second is a measurement error. And you're speaking about 50 ms from a single measurement. This is like coin flipping. Your web app may behave the same, changes are 50:50.